# Arduino Pong game Circuit Board Troubleshoot

Tags: arduino-uno, display, breadboard

I am following a tutorial online to make a pong game. I have managed to make quiet a lot work apart from my paddles in the game keep on shaking. The buttons do work fine, up and down on both ends.

[Tutorial Link](https://github.com/jerwil/Arduino_Pong)

I am sure, there is something with the power being supplied and not reaching to all points in the breadboard.

I am attaching a picture of my circuit board.[image] Any advice?

Thank you,
W

Answer (score 2):

The + and - along the bottom of the picture aren't connected to anything.
It also looks like this board has a separate left and right side.

So just make sure everything is connected along the sides.

Comment: Do you mean, I should supply the + & - from top side to the bottom?

Comment: No. They are split horizonally, in the middle. Both rails, upper and lower. Test continue with an ohmmeter and see yourself